# Siri Dictation Bypasses UITextView:shouldChangeTextInRange Delegate

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, siri, dictation

I use `(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)` to perform real-time regex validation on every character input into a `UITextView`.

This works well and even handles pasted text that might contain invalid characters.

But Siri doesn't seem to care for such things and dumps its dictation straight into `(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)theTextView`, bypassing the `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate and avoiding validation checks.

This seems like a security flaw to me and breaks the API flow that every other input channel follows.

Any thoughts as to how I can get Siri Dictation to comply with calling `shouldChangeTextInRange` ?

Comment: Dunno, but it sounds like [a good bug to file](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: I agree. Sounds like you should file a radar.

Comment: Bug reported to Apple.  Let's see what happens.

Comment: I see why you expect `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:` to be fired, but, as a current solution, you can look into `UITextInput` protocol, it has several dictation-related delegates.

Comment: Would love to see some updates on this question.  Like how to use UITextInput, and a link to the radar so we can track the progress and up-vote it (if Apple has that concept).  For now I catch textViewDidChange and just truncate the text if too long (the text from the end of the field, since I have no way to know where/what was added at that point).  Not ideal.

Comment: @SebastianDwornik, Any update on this?

Comment: From Apple: ```Engineering has determined that your bug report (18866525) is a duplicate of another issue (18306033) and will be closed.```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer....if:

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

is called then it's a user input. So put a BOOL in there to remember if the 'shouldChange' was checked.

then, microphone input will call:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

check your BOOL in here and if it's NO, then it's a microphone input.

(make the BOOL = NO at the end of textViewDidChange:)

That works great for me.

Comment: Hard to understand, poor wording, and most important, didn't work. Down-voted too.

Comment: that's the solution by the way if you don't want to dig into dictation delegates of UITextInput